# Cleaning a VS2010 WiX Installer project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.5, votive

I have a VS2010 solution with a WiX 3.5 (beta) Votive project, (as well as all the projects for the program that I am installing). When I clean the VS solution all of the program projects get properly cleaned, but the WiX project does not - the wixobj, wixpdb and msi files are not deleted.

So my questions are:

Is what I am seeing expected behavior?

If so what can I do so that these files are deleted when I clean the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this behavior is not correct. But you can find the same behavior on WiX 3.0 RTM too.

I have all my product build automated, and I have faced this issue with the following (obvious) steps:

- Cleaning the WiX - Visual Studio project.
- Deleting all the contents on **Bin/(Debug or Release)** folder.

Comment: Yeah .. I'm thinking a pre-build step to delete everything.  Its not like I am building the install all the time.  But I did waste time today on some builds which only came good after I manually deleted WiX's intermediate files

Answer (score 1):

To correct this behaivor, I think you should modify directly wixproj file. Open this file look at Target Name = "Clean" and change this to:

```
<Target Name = "Clean">
     <RemoveDir Directories="bin\$(Configuration)" />
     <RemoveDir Directories="obj\$(Configuration)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This approach is more thorough than what visual studio does during 'normal' cleaning. Anyhow I find this way useful if you change the name of the output through project files with a script. Such a change would otherwise make any previous output not detected for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Following works in one line also

```
<Target Name="CleanMe" AfterTargets="Clean">
<RemoveDir Directories="$(OUTDIR)"/>
</Target>
```